# Double Supremum Conflicting Conventions

Tags: notation, supremum-and-infimum, convention

We read $$\sup_{x\in X}(\sup_{y\in Y} f(x,y))$$
*left to right* (there's really no other choice), but **Question 1:** doesn't this contradict the following conventions?

1. Stuff inside parentheses is evaluated first
2. Composed functions (such as $\sup:X\to\mathbb{R}$ and $\sup:Y\to\mathbb{R}$) are read *right to left*

I guess one could argue 2. doesn't even apply, since they aren't composed functions at all (**Question 2:** what are they, actually?), but the entire thing still feels weird to me, especially since this entire thing seems to be understood implicitly and not defined explicitly.

Comment: It is the same thing as reading $f(g(x))$ left to right, but evaluating it inside to outside.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what you're talking about with convention (2); I'd "read" the expression $f\circ g$ as "f composed with g", from left to right.

Regarding the supposed contradiction with reading left to right and convention (1): No, there's no contradiction there; I can't imagine what you think the problem is. Consider a simpler example, the expression $$\sin(t^2).$$This is "read" from  left to right:

```
The sine of t squared.
```

So what?  The fact that we *pronounce* the word "sine" before we *pronounce* the word "squared" has nothing to do with how the expression is to be *evaluated*  - we need to evaluate $t^2$ first, so we know what to take the sine of. Math is the same on the planet htraE, although they read the expression as

```
.derauqs t fo enis ehT
```

Comment: Well, what I meant is that normally when we write $f(g(x))$, we evaluate $y=g(x)$, then $f(y)$ (and by reading composition right to left I basically just meant that the same holds for $(f\circ g)(x)$, not that we actually read the thing backwards; I apologize for the confusion). The problem I see with the supremums is that $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$ is nonsensical unless $x$ is already fixed, whereas for $f(g(x))$ we didn't need anything from $f$ to evaluate $g(x)$.

Comment: @BlondCafé But the expression $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$ is not nonsensical; it simply defines a function of $x$.

Comment: Okay intuitively that makes a lot of sense, and I hadn't thought about it that way (thank you!). But formally, I still don't get how all this follows from the definition of supremum. I thought $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$ was meant to be least upper bound of the set $\{f(x,y) \mid y\in Y\}$, but that set isn't even partially ordered, right? (I mean, $f(x,y_1)<f(x,y_2)$ doesn't make sense without a fixed $x$.) What am I missing?

Comment: @BlondCafé Yes, you take the $x$ to be the same for each value of $f(x,y)$ in that expression. Then, one "layer" higher, in the outer sup, you compare all the results for *each* value of $x$.

Comment: @BlondCafé Yes, $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$ is the least upper bound of $\{f(x,y):y\in Y\}$. Of course that set is ordered! It's a subset of $\Bbb R$; the "last upper bound" is with respect to the standard order on $\Bbb R$ as usual.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich When you say that $\{f(x,y)\mid y\in Y\}$ is ordered, I presume you're saying $\{f(x,y)\mid y\in Y\} = \{f(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$, in which case $\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y) = \sup \{f(x,y)\mid y\in Y\} = \sup \{f(x,y)\mid x\in X, y\in Y\}$, which would then equal $\sup_{(x,y)\in X\times Y}f(x,y)$ and also $\sup_{x\in X}f(x,y)$, in which case I'm very confused about all this notation. I'm sorry if I'm a little slow about all this, but I really don't see how this would work with the given definition of supremum.

Comment: No, when I say $\{f(x,y):y\in Y\}$ is ordered I mean that $\{f(x,y):y\in Y\}$ is ordered. The definition of supremum is irrelevant to how the notation is parsed. Define $F:X\to\Bbb R$ by $F(x)=\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)$. Then $\sup_{x\in X}\sup_{y\in Y}f(x,y)=\sup_{x\in X}F(x)$, by definition. I can't figure out what's confusing about this, or what you think somehow doesn't work.